# no executable node found problem in webstrom

Tags: javascript

I recently downloaded Webstorm Ide to study JS (I'm a beginner who doesn't know anything) 
Whenever I try to run the codes,a debugging problem (image right below) appears even if I downloaded node.js already.
How can I choose a right path and fix the problem ?

[image]

Comment: The button right next to the error message looks like a file selector prompt

Comment: I think you didn't install node correctly and it doesn't appear in the PATH, no?